# ¿A que se debe este error en wordpress y como se puede solucionar?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo hospedado en un servidor de godaddy en wordpress administrado una página, pero resulta que ya no se puede acceder al contenido de la página ni al administrador de wordpress, el error es el siguiente:
 `APCu is not configured correctly. Please refer to https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/apcu/installation/ for instructions.`

¿A que se debe y que puedo hacer para solucionarlo si al intentar ingresar al panel de administrador de wordpress me manda al mismo mensaje de error?

Comment: Tienes algún plugin en especial que estás utilizando?

Comment: ocupo algunos como: wpml, cherry-plugin, importer, cherry paralax plugin, fuera de ahi no tengo alguno otro  especial o especifico.
Pero no habia tenido ningún prolema hasta ahora.

Comment: La verdad que es raro tu problema. Puedes fijarte en este [enlace](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/apcu/) por si tienes información relevante

Comment: no me esta abriendo nada, dice pagina no encontrada, dentro de wordpress

Comment: Esta es la página: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/apcu/

Comment: si, ya la habia abierto aparte, contacte con soporte técnico del hosting y supuesta mente me dijerón que era por el cambio de versión de wordpress y que mientras se efectuaba el cambio tomaba de 24 a 72 hras.
¿Cree que deba a eso?

Comment: Sí, puede ser eso el inconveniente!

Answer (score 0):

Respalda y luego borra el archivo **object-cache.php** que está en **.../wp-content/**.

Comment: y el archivo ¿se eliminaría en forma temporal o permanente?

Answer (score 0):

[Es un problema de GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-WordPress/Wordpress-Managed-PHP-Version/m-p/30526) al actualizar PHP en sus servidores, debes contactarlos para que lo resuelvan.

Comment: voy a contactar, gracias